# Two lists of JSON values -- do operation on some key

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists of dictionaries which look like this:

```
x = [{'id':1,'num':5,'den':8},
     {'id':2,'num':3,'den':5},
     {'id':4,'num':11,'den':18},
     {'id':3,'num':2,'den':81},
     {'id':7,'num':10,'den':33}]

y = [{'id':1,'num':4,'den':9},
     {'id':6,'num':5,'den':11},
     {'id':3,'num':13,'den':83},
     {'id':2,'num':15,'den':28},
     {'id':4,'num':1,'den':2}]
```

Now, as it is clear, the keys in each (item) dict of both lists are same. For those elements, which have same `id`, I want a new list with corresponding `num = num(x) + num(y)` and `den = den(x) + den(y)`. So, in this case, output will be:

```
z = [{'id':1,'num':9,'den':17},
     {'id':2,'num':18,'den':33},
     {'id':4,'num':12,'den':20},
     {'id':3,'num':15,'den':164}]
```

How can this be achieved in the most "pythonic" way. Should I just brute force?

Comment: Is this some random downvote? How is this too broad...I don't think I could be more specific with the question

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but the reason for the downvote is quite evident. You need to specify what is it that you tried, and what is not working, etc.. (Especially for someone with your rep, etc.. ). Perhaps this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @karthikr The one who has downvoted has marked the question as too broad, so this is not the reason. I have mentioned in the question that I can do this by brute forcing it, but I am sure in python, there has to be some easier way. Nothing is not working, I just want to know the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve it using `list comprehension` as:

```
>>> [{'id': i['id'], 'num': i['num'] + j['num'], 'den': i['den'] + j['den']} for i in x for j in y if i['id'] == j['id']]
[{'num': 9, 'id': 1, 'den': 17}, {'num': 18, 'id': 2, 'den': 33}, {'num': 15, 'id': 3, 'den': 164}, {'num': 12, 'id': 4, 'den': 20}]
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know list comprehension can work like this, which would nest `for` by itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a somehow more readable solution :

```
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {'num': 0,'den': 0})
for data in x + y:
    match = result[data['id']]
    match['num'] += data['num']
    match['den'] += data['den']
    match['id'] = data['id']
z = list(result.values())
```

Comment: This will have those values as well in which case, `x[id]` and `y[id]` don't match, like ids 6,7 in my example. Though this is nice, I would prefer list comprehension as it is quite readable itself IMO.